# Spring WebClient set Bearer auth token in header

Tags: java, oauth, keycloak, webclient, spring-webclient

Following scenario:

I have two Microservices A and B. Service A is a Bearer client that has an open api and receives requests from clients that have to be authorized by keycloak. Now I want to send an authorized Request from Service A to Service B, which is also a bearer client.

I thought about adding the functionality as a filter function during the webclient builder process like

```java
@Bean
WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(authHeader())
            .build();
}

private ExchangeFilterFunction authHeader(String token) {
    return (request, next) -> next.exchange(ClientRequest.from(request).headers((headers) -> {
        headers.setBearerAuth(token);
    }).build());
}
```

This is an example I found in another question. It seems to to be the right way to me but can I provide the "String token" parameter at that stage of configuration?

I'm just switching from `RestTemplate` to `WebClient`, so sorry I this is a dump question.

EDIT:
I am able to set the header manually while building a new `WebClient`.

```java
return WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ context.getTokenString())
        .build();
```

As I know from the `RestTemplate`, it can be used as a Singleton. There also exists a `KeyCloakRestTemplate` which injects the header automatically.

`WebClient` is immutable, so when I inject it, I can't just use it and add the header afterwards.
In addition, I can't set this header on startup as I have to wait for a request to take the bearer header and pass it in. So I guess there is not other way than doing it this way?

Comment: It does not work for me if I set the bearer token as `default header`. I have to insert it as header when requesting. Any idea why?

Answer (score 9):

Or simply set it during the process of sending:

```
webClient.get()
    .uri(url)
    .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(token))
    .retrieve();
```

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using an [`ExchangeFilterFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html) filter in a similar situation.  In my case, I have a Spring component which retrieves the token to use.  If `context` in your `context.getTokenString()` example is a Spring bean, you should be able to do the same:

```java
@Bean
WebClient webClient(SomeContext context) {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter((request, next) -> next.exchange(
                    withBearerAuth(request, context.getTokenValue())))
            .build();
}

private static ClientRequest withBearerAuth(ClientRequest request, 
                                            String token) {
    return ClientRequest.from(request)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token)
            .build();
}
```